# Google Maps JS API: fitBounds and maintain center

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have an app where users set a home location and page through results. The home and results are displayed on the map. As the results displayed on the map change, the map adjusts to include all markers:

```
bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
//
// add markers to bounds
//
for (i = 0, l = markers.length; i < l; i ++) {
  bounds.extend(markers[i].getPosition());
}

this.map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

However, I also need to keep the map centered on the 'home' location.  The home marker is included in the bounds, but it is not necessarily the center.

I know that `this.setCenter(home)` will shift the map's center, but that will not necessarily ensure all the markers are still visible.

I've thought of finding the point the greatest distance from `home` and using that radius as a way of setting the bounds *around* `home` instead of just including `home`.  But if it isn't necessary to fit the whole circle into the square viewport, I'd prefer that.

Has anyone solved this?

#### Editing to answer my own question -

the linked question is a duplicate, but does not actually answer my question. LatLngBounds.contains() requires a LatLng and does not accept a bounds object: [LatLngBounds](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#LatLngBounds).  Led me in the right direction though.

```
map.fitBounds(bounds);
map.setCenter(center);
newbounds = map.getBounds();
for (i = 0; i < l; i ++) {
  if (!newbounds.contains(markers[i].getPosition())) {
    contained = false;
  }
}
if (!contained) map.setZoom(map.getZoom() - 1);
```

Comment: why don't you use **map.setCenter** ???

Comment: because calling it before calling `map.fitBounds(bounds)` it is irrelevant and calling it after does not necessarily keep all markers visible.